# Qual é a origem da expressão "foda-se" para expressar consternação?

Tags: origem-histórica, origem

Apesar desta expressão não ser geralmente muito bonita de se dizer, é muito usada — pelo menos em Portugal — para expressar consternação, por exemplo:

> Foda-se, esqueci-me das chaves dentro do carro.

O verbo "foder" tem, normalmente, dois significados: pode significar ter relações sexuais com outras pessoas; ou pode também significar *estragar* ou *arruinar*. O significado depende também um bocado de ser usado reflexivamente ou não...

É possível que este verbo derive dum verbo latim, porque existem verbos similares noutras línguas — como o «fottere» no italiano. No entanto, não existe a expressão "foda-se"...

Tendo em conta isto, a minha ideia é que "foda-se" deriva de quem a usa estar a expressar o facto que algo se estragou ou arruinou...

Mais outras ideias? Qual é a origem deste termo exatamente?

Comment: O significado dessa expressão é exatamente o mesmo que "dane-se", a única diferença é que uma é chula e pode ser usada em conotações sexuais, e a outra não.

Comment: Nesse contexto, *foda-se* é uma interjeição. Não consigo imaginar outra origem que não na mesma expressão no sentido *que se foda* (que se arruine, que se perca tudo, que se desgrace). O verbo *foder* era usado com um à-vontade chocante nas cantigas de escárnio e mal-dizer da idade média; depois rareia. Mas era usado no sentido literal (vi um único exemplo não inteiramente literal). Depois reaparece no final do séc. XX. Tou a falar da escrita, naturalmente. Com o verbo foi com certeza sempre usado na fala, não vejo como se possa documentar a origem dos usos figurado e interjetivo.

Comment: Acho que as pessoas que ficam fazendo esse tipo de pregunta poderiam fazer um esforço maior em termos de pesquisa. E para expressar consternação, acho que no Brasil, seria mas comun: Merda, cadé a minha chave?

Answer (score 5):

> A expressão foda-se não é recente. O Novo Dicionário de Calão de Afonso Praça, editado em 2001, cita a forma fosga-se, uma interjeição alternativa e menos grosseira para foda-se. Para Clotilde Almeida, isto significa que a palavra já existe há bastante tempo, pois até “já foram cunhadas formas alternativas da mesma que se encontram dicionarizadas”.
>
> José Pedro Machado, no Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa, uma das poucas obras dedicadas à etimologia portuguesa, refere que o verbo foder — do qual provém a palavra foda-se — vem do latim futere, que significa ter relações sexuais com uma mulher. Ainda de acordo com José Pedro Machado, o termo aparece em textos desde o século XII, não se sabendo ao certo quando terá sido cunhado.
> “Trata-se de uma expressão de desagrado que é bem portuguesa”, explicou Clotilde Almeida. Através de um processo de redução e de supressão, a palavra foda-se passou a (fo)dasse, mantendo o sentido original. Foi também a partir de foda-se que surgiram as formas fosga-se, fosca-se ou fónix, que querem dizer exatamente a mesma coisa. Estas foram criadas para suavizar (e ocultar) o sentido original do palavrão.

Fonte: [Jornal online "Observador"](http://observador.pt/especiais/palavrao-palavrao-vieram-as-asneiras/).

Comment: "Trata-se de uma expressão de desagrado que é bem portuguesa”.  Mas não é exclusiva da língua portuguesa.  Em Inglês existe o "fuck you" que significa exatamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: Fuck you não é foda-se, sejamos precisos. Foda-se é fuck it. Fuck  you é va te o se fuder.